# SimpleCRUD login failure

Tags: jsf, jpa, jakarta-ee, jaas, apache-tomee

**Platform I am using**:

- Fedora 20;
- mariadb-5.5.34-2.fc20.x86_64;
- Eclipse Kepler Service Release from www.eclipse.org;
- Apache TomEE plus 1.6.0.

I am implementing example

[See here](http://www.simtay.com/simple-crud-web-application-with-jsf-2-1-primefaces-3-5-maven-and-jpa/)

and I am trying to manage to work the login interface. My problem is that the login.xhtml webpage gets correctly the username and password, but the method

```
public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent)
```

of bean LoginController.java does not react correctly to the webpage login button. In particular, the webpage does not say anything about the correctness of the username & password. To see what it should happen, see the interactive example at the previous link.
[Here](http://youtu.be/G3Z0oemrrkA) instead, a short video of what happens on my computer.

To find out what is going on, I putted some console outputs inside the Java bean, and I found out that the getter/setter methods are working, the only method that does not work is

```
public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent)
```

Indeed the print

```
System.out.println("Entering in public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent)");
```

does not appear in console.

**Login.xml**

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
     <ui:define name="content">
         <h:form styleClass="loginPanelStyle">
                 <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />                        
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Login Panel
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="Username : "></h:outputText>
                <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginController.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Username!" message="fc">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="1" />  
                </p:inputText>
                <h:outputText value="Password : "></h:outputText>
                <p:password id="password" value="#{loginController.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter password!">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="1" />  
                </p:password>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" action="#{loginController.login}" 
    icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" />
                </f:facet> 
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
     </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I have also tried to replace

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" action="#{loginController.login}" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" />
```

with

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" action="#{loginController.login}" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" />
```

but the result is the same.

**LoginController.java**

```
package controller;

import util.DateUtility;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Login Controller class allows only authenticated users to log in to the web
 * application.
 *
 * @author Emre Simtay <emre@simtay.com>
 */
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private transient Logger logger;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of LoginController
     */
    public LoginController() {
        System.out.println("LoginController instantiated");
    }

    //  Getters and Setters
    /**
     * @return username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        System.out.println("getUsername: " + username);
        return username;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param username
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        System.out.println("setUsername sets username: " + this.username);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        System.out.println("getPassword is: " + password);
        return password;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param password
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        System.out.println("setPassword sets password: " + this.password);
    }

    /**
     * Listen for button clicks on the #{loginController.login} action,
     * validates the username and password entered by the user and navigates to
     * the appropriate page.
     *
     * @param actionEvent
     */
    public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Entering in public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent)");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            String navigateString = "";
            // Checks if username and password are valid if not throws a ServletException
            request.login(username, password);
            // gets the user principle and navigates to the appropriate page
            Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
            if (request.isUserInRole("Administrator")) {
                navigateString = "/admin/AdminHome.xhtml";
            } else if (request.isUserInRole("Manager")) {
                navigateString = "/manager/ManagerHome.xhtml";
            } else if (request.isUserInRole("User")) {
                navigateString = "/user/UserHome.xhtml";
            }
            try {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "User ({0}) loging in #" + DateUtility.getCurrentDateTime(), request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
                context.getExternalContext().redirect(request.getContextPath() + navigateString);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException, Login Controller" + "Username : " + principal.getName(), ex);
                context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error!", "Exception occured"));
                System.out.println("(DEBUG) CONSOLE OUTPUT: Error!, Exception occured");
            }
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error!", "The username or password you provided does not match our records."));
            System.out.println("(DEBUG) CONSOLE OUTPUT: Error!, The username or password you provided does not match our records.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listen for logout button clicks on the #{loginController.logout} action
     * and navigates to login screen.
     */
    public void logout() {

        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "User ({0}) loging out #" + DateUtility.getCurrentDateTime(), request.getUserPrincipal().getName());
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "/Login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

[Click here](https://github.com/Rendering/LAI_pezzi_Login/blob/master/src/META-INF/persistence.xml)

**web.xml**

[Click here](https://github.com/Rendering/LAI_pezzi_Login/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml)

**Project sources**:

You can find the whole "Login interface" project sources [HERE](https://github.com/Rendering/LAI_pezzi_Login/)

**TomEE configuration**

TomEE is using directories:

1. Main TomEE directory: apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0-JAAS
2. Eclipse's Servers workspace directory: /workspace/Server/TomEE-JAAS-config/

What is inside apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0-JAAS/config/ (1):

```
.
├── catalina.policy
├── catalina.properties
├── context.xml
├── groups.properties
├── logging.properties
├── login.config
├── server.xml
├── server.xml.original
├── system.properties
├── tomcat-users.xml
├── tomcat-users.xml.original
├── tomee.xml
├── users.properties
└── web.xml

0 directories, 14 files
```

What is inside (2):

```
.
├── catalina.policy
├── catalina.properties
├── context.xml
├── server.xml
├── tomcat-users.xml
└── web.xml
```

I uploaded both conf dirs [HERE](https://github.com/Rendering/tomee-jaas) so you can consult them.

To configure TomEE to operate with JAAS, I asked the [following question](http://pastebin.com/WRLpFvUY):
So I configured TomEE in Eclipse in this way

- http://imageshack.com/a/img856/6871/c384.png
- I added the JAAS tags in apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0-JAAS/conf/server.xml
- added login.config and login.properties in
  apache-tomee-plus-1.6.0-JAAS/conf/

**TomEE console**:

[Click here](http://pastebin.com/WRLpFvUY)

Comment: Can you post your web.xml file please?

Comment: You can find the Github link in the post :-)
I paste it again here
https://github.com/Rendering/LAI_pezzi_Login/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: Try to Change the attribute of the commandButton's tag to `actionListener` instead of `action`.

Comment: @Omar, fill an answer so I can give you the green mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the attribute of the commandButton's tag to `actionListener` instead of `action` should resolve the problem.